# Upper bound "Vicious nearest neighbour" algorithm suggestions

Tags: list-manipulation, algorithm

I am asking a question based on [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1459484/expected-number-of-people-to-not-get-shot) from the sister site MSE.

In an effort to make this a self-contained question, I include the fiorst documented posing of the problem by Robert Abilock in [**American Monthly** The Rifle-Problem](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2314274?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) *(R. Abilock; 1967)*,

> $n$ riflemen are distributed at random points on a plane. At a signal,
>   each one shoots at and kills his nearest neighbor. What is the expected
>   number of riflemen who are left alive?

*eg:* For $n=20,$ a random distribution might look something like this:

[image]

I would like to write an algorithm to find the upper bound for the number of survivors. As stated in the question, clerarly $n=1$ is a special case and the upper bound  $=1.$ For $n=2\rightarrow 8,$ the upper bound is obviously $n-2,$ though random point placements are not efficient for find possible arrangements for these:

```
Clear[aB, reP]

constA[nn_] := With[{aa = Partition[RandomReal[{0, 1}, 2 nn], 2]},
With[{cc = ({aa[[#]], First@Nearest[DeleteCases[aa, aa[[#]]], aa[[#]]]} & /@ 
Range@nn)}, With[{dd = Table[Position[aa, cc[[p, 2]]][[1, 1]], {p, nn}]}, 
With[{ee = Complement[Range@nn, dd]}, {aa, Length@ee}]]]]

constB[nn_, rr_] := With[{aa = constA[nn] & /@ Range@rr}, 
aa[[#]] & /@ Flatten@Position[aa[[All, 2]], Max@aa[[All, 2]]]]

whileF[nn_] := (reP = 1; While[Max@(aB = constB[nn, reP++])[[All, 2]] 
!= nn - Floor[nn/3]]; {Flatten[aB, 1]~Join~{{reP}}})
```

`whileF[n]` for $n\geq 8$ is just not viable - variants on a strategy are prefereable.

*eg:* an upperbound example for $n=8,$ where all but $\#\ 3$ and $4$ don't survive:

[image]

For $n\geq 9,$ the upper bound is not quite so obvious (though I believe for $n=9$ is $6$, and for $n=10,$ the upper bound of survivors is $7:$

[image]

*(image taken from [here](http://mks.mff.cuni.cz/kalva/short/soln/sh00g7.html)).*

I ask the question on this site, as it seems that the problem lends itself to graph networks and travelling salesman type algorithms.

I only ask for hints on where to begin, as requesting a code from scratch seems a little to much to ask. Any pointers would be most welcome.

Since the travelling salesman problem is an $NP$ problem, I would be happy for suggestions that deal with small $n$ only.

Comment: I don't think this is the standard usage of "lim sup". For any `n` there must be a supremum, but I fail to see where a limit would be involved.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau you are quite right, my mistake - will alter - sorry for confusion!

Comment: Please make the question self-contained (as per the StackExchange policy).

Comment: @Pickett updated - please feel free to suggest further improvements

Comment: The graph can be constructed with `NearestNeighborGraph[points, DirectedEdges -> True]`.

Comment: @Szabolcs thanks - had no idea this function existed - will look into how it can be appolied here.

Comment: So this would take one sample of the number of survivors: `Count[VertexInDegree@NearestNeighborGraph[RandomReal[1, {n, 2}], DirectedEdges -> True], 0]`

Comment: @Szabolcs that's great, but don't see how that helps with finding an upper bound (since `RandomReal` is probably not the most efficient way to find the upper bound).

Comment: It doesn't, sorry.

Comment: Aren't the optimal arrangements like this? ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/FjoJD.png)

Comment: @belisariusisforth I can't see how that would work, but I may well be being a bit slow here - wouldn't you get equal distances though? Do you have any coordinateas that this works for? I can only get 11 for 16 - can you manage 12? If you are right - this could lower the upper bound significantly ..

Comment: @martin As it's an hexagonal lattice I get equal distances indeed. That's the main idea. Then I choose the neighbor so to minimize the kills. Twelve out of sixteen alive here (if I counted them right) ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/MbWqc.png)

Comment: @belisariusisforth looks promising - will give it a go in the morning (very late here!) on hexagonal lattice & get back to you on it - looks good though! :)

Comment: @belisariusisforth try the following:

Comment: `With[{n = 16},Module[{}, r = {{2, Sqrt[3]},{2, 2*Sqrt[3]},{5/2, Sqrt[3]/2}, {5/2, (3*Sqrt[3])/2}, {5/2, (5*Sqrt[3])/2}, {7/2, Sqrt[3]/2}, {7/2, (3*Sqrt[3])/2}, {7/2, (5*Sqrt[3])/2}, {3, Sqrt[3]}, {3, 2*Sqrt[3]}, {4, Sqrt[3]},{4,2*Sqrt[3]}, {5, Sqrt[3]}, {5, 2*Sqrt[3]}, {9/2, (3*Sqrt[3])/2}, {11/2, (3*Sqrt[3])/2}}; Deploy[Graphics[{Table[ With[{i=i},Locator[Dynamic[r[[i]]]]], {i, n}], Dynamic[Arrow[shot = Table[{r[[j]], First[Nearest[Table[r[[i]], {i, Delete[Range[n], j]}],r[[j]]]]}, {j,n}]]]},PlotLabel -> Dynamic["Survivors =" <>ToString[n - Length[DeleteDuplicates[shot[[All, 2]]]]]]]]]]`

Comment: @belisariusisforth can you squeeze 12 out of this? I think it is the equal distances that is causing the problem ...

Comment: @martin I find no point in exploring the hexagonal lattice that way. Each point has 6 nearest neighbors at the same distance. The trick is how to select the one that left more republicans alive

Comment: @belisariusisforth is it possible to manually adjust pts to exploit your method, or is manual adjustment too sensitive?

Comment: @martin lemme think. Probably tomorrow.

Comment: [9 men, 7 survivals](http://i.stack.imgur.com/cV6tr.png) :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Edit on the general solution:

As we can see, from 2 to 9 the survival rate is increasing monotonously, and there seems to be no way to add a new point into the above solution of 9 without increasing death, so **my general conjecture** is: for any $n$ points ($n$ been fixed), the solution reaching max survival number is **to divide $n$ points to clusters of size 2 to 9 and far from each other, with priorties on those with higher survival rates**.

The code is as following:

```
Clear[survivalPredict]
survivalPredict[numOfPoints_Integer] /; numOfPoints >= 2 :=
    Module[{factorSet = {}, survivalNum = {7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0}},
        Fold[
            Function[{remain, clusterSize},
                AppendTo[factorSet, Quotient[remain, clusterSize]];
                Mod[remain, clusterSize]
                ],
            numOfPoints,
            Reverse@Range[2, 9]
            ];
        factorSet.survivalNum
        ]
```

(Note if there is 1 single point left, e.g. for `survivalPredict[10]`, it won't increse or decrease the survival number.)

Compare it to OP's guess on Math.StackExchange:

```
Module[{numOfPoints, numOfSurvivals, opsGuess},
    {numOfPoints, numOfSurvivals, 
            opsGuess} = {#, survivalPredict[#], 
                        If[# <= 8, # - 2, # - Floor[#/3]]} & /@ Range[2, 44];
    opsGuess = 
        MapThread[
            If[#2 == 1, 
                    Item[#1, Background -> Hue[0, 0.13, 1]], #1] &, {opsGuess, 
                Unitize[opsGuess - numOfSurvivals]}];
    Grid[Prepend[{numOfPoints, numOfSurvivals, opsGuess}, 
                StringSplit[
                    "# of men,# of survivals: my guess,# of survivals: OP's guess", 
                    ","]]]
    ]
```

[image: general solutions]

An example solution for 44 points:

### [image: Mathematica graphics]

## The original answer

This is not a complete answer, the main idea is to show that at the situation of 9 men, the number of survivals can reach **7** instead of **6** (as guessed by OP).

The code is as following, use mouse to drag the nodes, <kbd>Alt</kbd> + click to create/delete a node, solid nodes are the deads while holo ones are survivals. Basically you want to place new node both **outside any red circles** and **inside the Voronoi region of an already-dead node**.

```
Needs["ComputationalGeometry`"]

Clear[survivalFunc]
survivalFunc[posLst_] /; 
        MatchQ[posLst, {{_Real, _Real} ..}] :=
    Module[{nearestFunc, deads},
        nearestFunc = Nearest[posLst];
        deads = nearestFunc[#, 2][[2]] & /@ posLst;
        Complement[posLst, deads]
        ]

Clear[virtualize]
virtualize[posLst_] /; 
        MatchQ[posLst, {{_Real, _Real} ..}] :=
    Module[{nearestFunc},
        nearestFunc = Nearest[posLst];
        Show[{
                Disk[#, Norm[# - nearestFunc[#, 2][[2]]]] & /@ posLst // 
                    Graphics[
                            Join[{EdgeForm[Opacity[.4, Hue[0, 0.29, 1]]], 
                                    Opacity[.1, Hue[0, 0.21, 1]]}, #]] &,
                 Graphics[{Hue[0.1, 0.28, 0.89], 
                        Cases[DiagramPlot[posLst], _Line, ∞]}],

                NearestNeighborGraph[posLst],

                Graphics[{
                        AbsolutePointSize[10], Hue[0.6, 0.51, 0.73],
                        Point[posLst],
                        AbsolutePointSize[6], White,
                        Point[survivalFunc[posLst]]
                        }]
                }, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> 2 {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, 
            ImageSize -> Scaled[1]]
        ]

DynamicModule[{pts = N@{{-.3, 0}, {.3, 0}}}, 
    LocatorPane[Dynamic[pts], 
                Dynamic[virtualize@pts], 
                Appearance -> None, LocatorAutoCreate -> True]
        ]
```

[image: solution of 9]

And of course this solution of 9 can be "stacked" to get a solution of 18:

[image: solution of 18]

And the similar strategy can give 9 survivals out of 12 (instead of [OP's guess on math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1460890/13585) which is $12-\lfloor 12/3 \rfloor = 8$):

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: looks good to me :) Upper bound improved! :D - Do you think this (ie strings of 9 in these arraqngements) is optimal? I am guessing not, and there may well be a more complex underlying structure to the upper bounds problem. Please feel free to correct me if I am being slow, and have missed something obvious in your answer about his already!

Comment: @martin Regarding the more complex structure, I suspect the some as you. But right now this cluster solution is the best I can shape. (And I also have a small bit of belief that this might be the optimized one as I failed to see any other strategies.)

Comment: @martin Thanks for the acceptance and the bounty! I thought about the problem today. I think another way to rephrase it is think it like a crystal/lattice with imperfection. A solution might be found by trying all kinds of perturbations around the shape of a perfect triangle mesh.

Comment: It was a difficult decision, but what swayed it for me was that it answered the question of the upper bound directly. I think you are right, it is not a straightforward problem, and I will conditue to explore via your code & possible lattice structures. If you decide to play any further with it, please update answer to include any developments! Thanks once again :)

Answer (score 15):

(Notebook: https://github.com/arnoudbuzing/rifleproblem)

OK, this is not a full blown solution (I can delete it when there is a real answer), but perhaps a useful tool to help others get a feel for the problem:

```
RifleProblem[n_Integer] := DynamicModule[{rifle, shot, nearest},
  rifle = RandomReal[1, {n, 2}];
  Deploy[
   Graphics[{
     Dynamic[
      Arrow[shot = 
        Table[{Part[rifle, j], 
          First[Nearest[
            Table[Part[rifle, i], {i, Delete[Range[n], j]}], 
            Part[rifle, j]]]}, {j, n}]]],
     {Opacity[0.5], 
      Table[With[{i = i}, 
        Dynamic[If[Not@MemberQ[shot[[All, 2]], Part[rifle, i]], 
          Disk[Part[rifle, i], 
           EuclideanDistance[Part[rifle, i], 
            Part[shot, i, 2]]], {}]]], {i, n}]},
     Table[
      With[{i = i}, 
       Locator[Dynamic[Part[rifle, i]], 
        Dynamic[If[MemberQ[shot[[All, 2]], Part[rifle, i]], 
          Style["\[FreakedSmiley]", 36, Background -> Red], 
          Style["\[HappySmiley]", 36, Background -> Green]]]]], {i, n}]
     }, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, 
    PlotLabel -> 
     Dynamic[Style[
       Framed["Survivors = " <> 
         ToString[n - Length[DeleteDuplicates[shot[[All, 2]]]]]], 16, 
       Orange, Background -> Black]]
    ]]]
```

For example, this lets you drag the locators in the graphic and experiment with how to optimize for the number of survivors:

[image]

Comment: @Arnould thanks -- certainly makes playing around with solutions a little easier :)

Comment: Thanks... I'm going to play with this a bit to build my intuition. I think you're right about the upper bound for the n=10 case being 7.

Comment: once you have placed the locators, is it possible to export the coordinates?

Comment: nicely done! This is inspired!! :D